# Array of Strings scanning Properly, then Running Together

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a function that is designed to read multiple strings from an input file so I can call them back later.  That is coded as follows:

```
int load_mpn_search(char search_filename[], int size, char search_array[][5])
{
int search_size = 0;
int n = 0;
FILE * infile;
int i = 0;


infile = fopen(search_filename, "r");

if(infile==NULL)
{
    printf("\nUnable to open %s\n", search_filename);
}

else
{   
printf("\n\nDuring Scan:");
    while(fscanf(infile, "%s\n", search_array[n]) != EOF)
            {
                printf("\n%d  %s",n, search_array[n]);
                n++;
            }

            search_size = n;
}
fclose(infile);
```

This appears to pull all of the strings in properly from the input file, and store them in the array.  I use the print function to show me what is being stored, and what I get back is:

```
During Scan:
0  2-1-0
1  1-0-2
2  1-3-5
3  1-10
4  3-3-0
5  5-1-0
6  5-1-0-1
7  5-2-1
```

However, immediately after in the same program, I try to print them back to see what is stored using this:

```
printf("\n\nIn Function:");


for(i = 0; i < search_size; i++)
{
    printf("\ni = %d", i);
     printf("\t search_array[%d] = %s", i, search_array[i]);
}
```

and what I get back is:

```
In Function:
i = 0    search_array[0] = 2-1-01-0-21-3-51-10
i = 1    search_array[1] = 1-0-21-3-51-10
i = 2    search_array[2] = 1-3-51-10
i = 3    search_array[3] = 1-10
i = 4    search_array[4] = 3-3-05-1-05-1-05-2-1
i = 5    search_array[5] = 5-1-05-1-05-2-1
i = 6    search_array[6] = 5-1-05-2-1
i = 7    search_array[7] = 5-2-1
```

Each string should only be 5 characters long, except for i = 6, which is 7 characters long, yet it appears the program is bunching them together into a seemingly random collection and repeating through the file to fill all strings in the array.  Any help would be sincerely appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: size your array correctly and you won't have a problem - a `char` array needs to be 1 larger than the number of characters in it so you can store the NUL terminator at the end

Comment: Please stop bean-counting. Unless you are stuck with a RAM-restricted embedded system, estimate your string size, round it up to the nearest 128 boundary and double it.  Shtap messing about:)

Comment: this function load_mpn_search doesn't end with a }

Comment: Because you tried to store more than 5 chars in a 5-char array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string length is not quite enough

```
int load_mpn_search(char search_filename[], int size, char search_array[][5]);
```

increase the size

```
int load_mpn_search(char search_filename[], int size, char search_array[][128]);
```

Note you need to accommodate space for '\0' as well.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `char search_array[][5]` is one char too small for e.g. `1-2-3`, which is six including `\0`. As a result, upon each `fscanf`, the terminating null character of the previous entry is overwritten. Entry 3 is less than 6 so its terminator is not overwritten.